# How to determine the argument of constructor and insert function?

Tags: java, function, constructor, insert

I have a Song class as follow

```
public class Song {
    protected String title;
    protected String artiest;
    ...}
```

and a Node class which inherits the Song class

```
public class Node extends Song{
    protected Node next;
    ...}
```

Finally, there is a List class which has a Node object

```
public class List {
    protected Node head;
    ...}
```

Now I need to write the constructor and insert functions for each class. 
My problems is **how to determine the number of those functions and the argument list of those functions.** 
To be special, take the List class as example. I know I must have the constructor like

```
public List() {
    head = null;
}


public List(List source) {
    copy_from_list(this.head, source.head);
}

public List(Node source){
        Node temp = New Node(source);
        temp.set_next(head);
        hand = temp;
    }
```

and insert function

```
public void insert(Node source) {
    Node temp = new Node(source);
    temp.set_next(head);
    head = temp;
}
```

Do I need one more constructor with String as argument?

```
public List(String title, String artiest) {
    Node temp = new Node(title, artiest);
    temp.set_next(head);
    head = temp;
    }
```

and one more insert function with String as argument?

```
public void insert(String title, String artiest){...}
```

Or it depends on the need, which means I need it if I want to insert two Strings title_source and artiest_source to List directly.

Thanks for reading. Waiting for reply.

Comment: You seem to be building a linked list. Why not use the LinkedList implementation that ships with java?

Comment: You shouldn't.  The "title" and "artist" are properties of a `Node`, so your program should use a `new Node` to create an object that carries those properties.  You *could* add a convenience method to `List` to insert the title and artist directly, but it's probably not necessary and doesn't help make the program more readable.